# Please offer comments, critique on self-resonating invented buck joule thief converter for third world use

Tags: circuit-design, buck, led-driver, resonance

Even though I'm not an EE, I have simulated the Joule Thief to death in LTSpice, but I have not yet made a prototype of this circuit. I have a friend who is an EE who won a contract to light some areas in the third world, like refugee, kind of areas, and I would like to propose my circuit to them, but I don't want to propose a bad circuit, or for it to have any glaring flaws, etc.

Unfortunately, I'm guessing that the circuit may be too expensive with the custom coupled-magnetics piece that will be required, but I don't know how much they cost. I see them in cheapo USB 120V=>5V,2A wall adapters / USB chargers, and bug zapper circuits, so I really don't know.

Please let me know if you think this will work. I somehow think this should have been invented already, but haven't seen this before, so perhaps there's something wrong with it? Thanks ahead of time for letting me know what you think, how it could be improved, are there any flaws, etc. Or I might need to add missing parasitics, or could benefit from using a different spice / other simulator.

[image]

---

Edit 1

I am aware that a linear solution may work here, and it's still one of the options being considered. We still may need this design in this, or other, circumstances.

To clarify a little...

Overarching goal is to make people feel safer, and be safer. This is just a small part, and only represents lighting the inside of the outhouses. We must light outhouses internally to make people feel safe, and be able to perform standard toilet tasks, like monthly menses, and go to the bathroom. Well-lit provides a feeling of safety in addition to some real protection. If they don't feel safe, they won't use the facilities, which creates problems. So, we must protect women and children from predators of all kinds, if you know what I mean. (Think refugee camp.) Therefore, the lighting must maintain brightness all night, summer and winter. And to protect women and children during midnight outhouse trips, lighting must be even and reliable (but also efficient and long-lasting and cost-optimized). While this is a specific design, please, if you would, also evaluate this circuit in the general sense, for other uses in other projects.

Comment: Is [almost] any circuit required? LEDs might simply run from LiFePO4 with nearly no resistance at all. The light output will be variable, and perhaps temperature runs high at full charge, or lifetime isn't so reliable, or charge use is shallow, but these might be acceptable compromises in such circumstances.

Comment: @TimWilliams -- Duly noted, and a linear solution has been on the table (for this configuration). But this design may be needed in other circumstances, and so the question still stands. Your comment now answered in question.

Comment: What is it's benefit over other designs that do the same thing. It's that that is important.

Comment: Looks very expensive compared to just a linear current regulator

Comment: I thought a Joule Thief was to drain a battery down to zero. That's a bad idea for a lithium cell you plan to recharge, and why the circuit should have a cut off below about 2.5V.  I'm not seeing that in this circuit.

Comment: @user1908704 -- Thanks for the observation. I'm leaving certain details out because there's enough information there already. FYI, The picture contains text showing that I plan to use a digital potentiometer at R1 to maintain even brightness, which needs a microcontroller to sense the voltage and adjust R1 according to a table with interpolation. The microcontroller should be able to also implement UVLO, and probably other typical LED driver features. Also, UVLO should mostly not be necessary for this application, as charging and discharging should occur daily.

Comment: Why an MCU when an analog solution can implement that more simply?

Comment: @TimWilliams -- Pairing a microcontroller with an analog solution has certain advantages that can't be beat by analog by itself. Probably the greatest is if you have problems that you didn't count on -- a part out of spec, requirements that you were unaware of, a feature you didn't think of that you need.  The microcontroller opens up the possibility of handling all of these "problems" or "opportunities" with a firmware update, which is simpler than a physical change of circuit. Yes, coding and programming are costly, but more costly are mistakes from which you can't gracefully recover.

Comment: Then... an acceptable answer is "just do it all in software", no?  (I'm not sure how heart-set you are on the JT thing. But it sounds like the scope extends well beyond a power-switching core, so would be worthy of consideration. Maybe not in this question, but grounds for another perhaps.)

Comment: Also, software recovery assumes the end user (or other responsible party) has, or has access to, all of the dev tools and equipment required to do that; so, at least a PC, an internet connection (if relevant software is not already loaded), and likely a lot of docs to work with all of these things. That's a heck of a lot more than a handful of transistors desoldered from a board or something, so it would be good to have a solid grounding of what can and can't go here, and why.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD I think you need to clearly state your design requirements to make the question make sense.  I mean in terms of what technical goals you have: low cost, bright light, long runtime, high efficiency, reliability, easy charging, ...?  You've presented (part of) a circuit here, but without the goals we don't know whether it's an appropriate design or not. Which goals are you prepared to sacrifice in order to achieve others?

Comment: @user1908704 -- Please vote to close my question, as needs details or clarity, and I will ask to reopen when I have updated the question with more specifics. I expect to finish within a week.

Comment: @TimWilliams -- Please vote to close my question, as needs details or clarity, and I will ask to reopen when I have updated the question with more specifics. I expect to finish within a week.

Comment: I have to go to the web site that explains some of the requirements and parse lots of text, and interpret it into some of the requirements. I have to do some measurements, and make some judgement calls for other requirements. I have to talk to my EE friend for other requirements. Unfortunately, every refugee camp will have additional requirements, likely. And we will learn as we do this, too. Finally, I'm just trying to help. and not really officially part of the team. So I'm really just trying to provide an efficient circuit that we can play with for different scenarios.

Comment: It should be cheap, efficient, indestructable, hard to sabotage, works in the coldest temperatures on Earth, and the hottest temperatures on Earth too. We should be able to split hairs better as we get further along.  This is why I want up to a week to collect data and **try** to give a more specific scenario as the question.

Comment: Aside: hah, didn't realize you could vote to close your own post, but I guess that checks out. Anyway, glad this has been of some use -- engineering at its best is drawing together multidisciplinary requirements of an often vague nature, to hopefully produce a product of value to customers and shareholders alike; and it sounds like we've found some more of those corners to peer into. I look forward to the edit, cheers!

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=created%3a2024%20%5bled%5d&searchOn=3

Answer (score 4):

Your application needs light at night and not at daytime so why not look at cheap solar garden light which have very simple circuit

Comment: That's a great idea. But we'll want our product to last much longer than these products typically last. So we'd probably want to use one of the discrete versions that can be found, and then make it our own. Once again, great idea!

Comment: The products that  dont last have bad waterproofing .Also the Nicad cells have a short life .Adress this and you will be fine .

Answer (score 4):

You can make a self-oscillating buck converter LED driver very easily by using just one inductor + feedback winding.

The important part is to determine the value of C1. Its capacitance has to be such that the voltage on the right side of C1 measured against ground (Gnd) has a nice slope during the ON cycle (blue waveform), which means that the transistor is quickly turning off.

The green current through inductor L1 (and the LED) ensures low losses, since all current from the charged inductor (coil) is transferred to the LED.

[image: Image of Self-Oscillating Buck Converter and LED driver]

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware of this circuit. Where did you find it / learn it?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD Nowhere. I just realized it can be done this way 4 years ago. I tried to build it, even with feedback, it worked. Maybe someone did the same, who knows.

Comment: I tested it by supplying from 2m2 standalone capacitor charged to 40V. It had a very good performance, i.e. it last very long time. The biasing was different of course.